# Issue while page refresh in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, webpack-dev-server, reactstrap

I am facing an issue while loading the simplelineicons font in a react app.The issue happens when the page is refreshed from a child component.When the page is refreshed from a parent component i see that the font file is loaded correctly.

Here is the code:
In Full.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="/courses" component={Courses}/>
</Switch>
```

In Courses.js the route is defined as below:

```
const Courses = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/courses" component={Course}/>
    <Route path="/courses/info" component={Info}/>
  </Switch>
)
```

When i refresh the page with url /courses/info i see that the font file is not loading as url is appended with courses as below:

> http://localhost:8080/courses/js/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.78f07e2c2a535c26ef21d95e41bd7175.woff

but it should not have courses in the above url.It should be:

> http://localhost:8080/js/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.78f07e2c2a535c26ef21d95e41bd7175.woff

I am not sure how courses is appended in the url

I am using the below in webpack config:

```
{
   test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
   loader: 'file-loader?name=/js/fonts/[name].[ext]',
    options: {
       name: './fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
   }
}
```

Can someone please help me how to resolve this issue.Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the below in webpack config:

```
{
 test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
 loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{
   test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
       name: '/fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]'
   }
}
```

relative path syntax is used by you. it should be absolute. Please let me know it helped

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have tried this but it did not work.Also when I refresh with url /courses everything works fine but with url /courses/info it fails.Can you please help me on this.

Comment: how you are including your font file. In index.html or via import statements?

Comment: i am including the font css file via import(import 'simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css';).

Comment: now check for the path of font file . What it is showing up now?

Comment: I have not explicitly loaded the font file.I thought it should be taken care by the file-loader.can you please tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Right now i am not sure, why its not working , but you can debug it 
by writing this statement
import fontPath from 'simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css';
and print in 
render() {
console.log("fontPath", fontPath)
//see what you get
return (

)
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161897/discussion-between-user3062513-and-stack26).